# Incorrect icon in Recent achievements tab and Featured section

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, achievements-dialog, featured-questions

Today I surprisingly found out that the Recent achievements tab is shown with Cross Validated icon instead of the normal StackOverflow icon.

[image: Recent achievements tab is shown with Cross Validated's icon]

[image: Featured section with Cross Validated's black-and-white icon]

[image: A Skeptics Hot network question with Software Engineering icon]

I can replicate this on both Chrome and FF. Reloading doesn't help; DevTools remains silent. It seems that the `background-position` property is messed up somehow, yet this is not the case with most other HNQs.

Comment: This seems to be affecting other SE sites as well. I'm fine with this question being migrated to [meta.se], if anyone feels that's the more suitable place.

Comment: This is likely due to the [langdev.se] site going into public beta, and havings its sprites added to the list. (At least, that's what's caused similar issues in the past.)

Comment: Dupe on Meta.SE: [sub-stack icons are shifted / mixing-in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390757)

Comment: This is a typical issue when SE updates their sprites. It can be anything from real problems in the sprite sheets or their code to just caching. It's always amazed me, given that they *repeatedly* have this problem, that they don't organize their sprite sheet such that this *can't happen*, or at least such that it *won't happen as often*, and so adding a new site is *so much easier*. In other words, stick the block of icons to which you're commonly adding images at the end and add to the end of that block, so everything else doesn't need to move around when a common operation is performed.

Comment: Alternately, just preallocate a larger amount of blank space that's reserved for potential new site icon sprites, then add new ones in there, so adding a site doesn't move everything around (and deleting can just leave holes or be no change).

Comment: Should be fixed now, but I can't confirm since I'm not experiencing the issue in the first place. Are you seeing correct icons now?

Comment: @AdamLear Yes, everything looks good.

Comment: @AdamLear [Many communities in my community navigator and HNQ sidebar entry have the wrong icon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425399/6296561)

Comment: @AdamLear I still experience the HNQ issue on main StackOverflow only. To reproduce, we need: Dark Mode ON + monitor resolution higher than 1. We then hit the CSS rule `@media only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:3/2), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5)
body.theme-dark .favicon` which still points to the https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/favicons-sprite32-dark.png?v=bac20add62c5 version of the spritesheet, itself still containing the duplicate **PLD** icons.

Comment: @AdamLear, it seems that the server cache caught up on this since yesterday. It now looks fine. Thanks if you were involved in this resolution.

Comment: Just got an icon that looks like popcorn (I think that's supposed to be for movies.SE?) for music.SE. Makes me wonder if someone's trying to put them in alphabetical order and adding a new one shifts everything else.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That sounds about right. Sites are ordered by their subdomains in the spritesheet linked above by Kaiido (i.e. [ham.se] (`ham`) goes after [alcohol.se] (`alcohol`)) whereas they are ordered by site names in the Community tab (i.e. vice versa).