# Site icons in the site switcher dropdown are incorrect

Tags: bug, top-bar, favicon, stack-exchange-button

On the Stack Overflow site (not Meta Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange, or any other site) the icon for Stack Overflow is the generic Stack Exchange icon, and Meta Stack Overflow icon is the Meta Stack Exchange icon. Also, the Meta Stack Exchange icon is replaced with Stack Apps' icon, and Stack Apps' icon is Quality Assurance and Testing's icon:

[image]

Could this be fixed?

Comment: Can't find a tag for the dropdown control that I'm talking about, so if someone finds one, please retag :P

Comment: Wow; the internal tests are striking too. We must have a compelling case. :D

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390757/sub-stack-icons-are-shifted-mixing-in

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425362/incorrect-icon-in-recent-achievements-tab-and-featured-section

Comment: I don't reproduce this. This is the Stack Exchange MultiCollider SuperDropdown, by the way. No idea why there isn't a tag for it. :-)

Comment: It's not consistent, e.g. for me everything is fine. The server side cache is spread across several servers, and it's all one big mess, but all same root cause.

Comment: @Cody [there is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-button?tab=Active)

Comment: Perfect. Don't ping a moderator, use the "Edit tags" button. :-)