# Many communities in my community navigator and HNQ sidebar entry have the wrong icon

Tags: bug, favicon

See the below image.

[image: An image of my community list and part of the Hot Network Questions list]

[Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour), [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tour) have the wrong icon. I think Stack Overflow has the wrong icon as well. This also only happens on Stack Overflow. As far as I can tell, when checking on a stackexchange.com site, the icons are correct.